# Does Android app dynamically change its Target API Level

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-12

I have a Xamarin.Forms app targeting Android API Level 30 (Android 11) which had Xamarin.Twilio.AudioSwitch v1.1.3 installed. The app is available in Play Store and was working fine till the time Android 12 was not released.

As soon as Android 12 became available, I got complaints from users using the BLE functionality of the app that they are not able to connect with BLE devices supported by the application.

The Android 12 users were getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException:
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:2437)
at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:2421)
at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2404)
at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2346)
at android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy.getRemoteName (IBluetooth.java:5470)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.getName (BluetoothDevice.java:1889)
at crc....Adapter_Api21BleScanCallback.n_onScanResult (Native Method)
at crc....Adapter_Api21BleScanCallback.onScanResult (Adapter_Api21BleScanCallback.java:38)
at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper$1.run (BluetoothLeScanner.java:646)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8641)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:567)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```

The above exception occurs due to the [Android 12 Bluetooth permission changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android12-or-higher). But this is required only if the app targets API Level 31. But since my app targets API level 30, I was not expecting these changes to be required in my app.

On investigating the issue, I found out that the issue is due to the native Audio Switch v1.1.3 targeting Android API Level 31 (Android 12) as mentioned here: [Twilio Audio Switch v1.1.3](https://github.com/twilio/audioswitch/releases/tag/1.1.3) but the Xamarin.Twilio.AudioSwitch v1.1.3 binding library specifies MonoAndroid 9.0 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Twilio.AudioSwitch/1.1.3) due to which I was able to install it for a project targeting API Level 30.

Does this mean that if the app has a package which targets an Android API Level higher than the app itself, the target API level would be dynamically change to higher API level?

Now the problem that I am facing is that I am not able to get this issue fixed for the users who already have the app installed.

I did a downgrade of Xamarin.Twilio.AudioSwitch to v1.1.2 as the native Audio Switch v1.1.2 library targets Android API Level 30 (Android 11) and found that the issue gets solved for new installations of the app. If a user already using a previous version of my app which had the Audio Switch v1.1.3 package and updates to the latest version of app which is using Audio Switch 1.1.2, the user still faces the above exception.

Is there any way that this can be fixed without making the app target Android API level 31 (Android 12) as that would require significant changes to the app?

**Note:** Asking the users to reinstall the app is not an option for me.

Comment: Presumably the app can't "dynamically change its target API" - as you said, targetting higher API would "require significant changes to the app". Rather, the question is what is being saved, and where, that causes the app to behave differently when upgraded, compared to a fresh install. As a test, have one of those users go to that app's App Info / Storage / Clear Cache. Does that help? How about App Info / Storage / Clear data? If either of these helps, that would be a clue, that might help you to find what you need the update to clear/reinitialize, to get it working.

Comment: I have tried doing clear data and cache both. But the app still behaves the same unless reinstalled :(

Comment: Have you tried powering off phone after app update + clear app data? If it isn't being remembered by the app, then something is being remembered elsewhere. Simultaneously clearing app data AND rebooting device should clear everything, AFAIK.

Comment: Have you tried to update from `AudioSwitch 1.1.3` to latest version 1.14?  AudioSwitch 1.1.3 added support to Android 12, because of the bluetooth changes, but also introduced some bugs.  AudioSwitch 1.1.4 fixes those bugs. You

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Phone restart and clear app data did not make any difference. Looks like it is something persisted by Android OS.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Updating to AudoSwitch 1.1.4 would require the application to target Android API Level 31. Trying to install v1.1.4 gives this message: "Package Xamarin.Twilio.AudioSwitch 1.1.4 is not compatible with monoandroid11.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v11.0). Package Xamarin.Twilio.AudioSwitch 1.1.4 supports: monoandroid12.0 (MonoAndroid,Version=v12.0)"

Answer (score 1):

--- This is only supposed to be needed if you **target** SDK 31 (but need legacy Bluetooth support), but its worth a try ---

- Close solution.
- In a text editor, edit file `YourProject.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml`, with changes below.
- Rebuild solution.

**CHANGE 1:**

[Bluetooth permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions#declare-android12-or-higher), point 4., recommends:

Add `android:maxSdkVersion="30"` to each declared Bluetooth-related permission. Example from doc's code snippet:

```xml
<!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions on older devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
```

Perhaps this will clear whatever the OS is remembering re your app's Bluetooth access.

**CHANGE 2 (experiments):**

EITHER: REMOVE any Bluetooth permissions that were added in SDK 31. ONLY list permissions that existed in SDK 30.

OR: list the permissions app WOULD need if targeted SDK 31, but add `android:maxSdkVersion="30"`, similar to above.

Also consider point 5.:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
                     android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
```

maybe as:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="30"
                     android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
```

What we are doing here is not standard -- "should" simply be ignored on a "target SDK 30" app -- it is an attempt to get OS to clear something it is remembering related to this app.
**Hypothesis** is that during OS upgrade, OS noticed which apps were using Bluetooth in a way that required additional permissions [due to Twilio.AudioSwitch v1.1.3], and marked them as needing those additional permissions. But then failing when feature used, because permission not declared in manifest.

Comment: Hi @ToolmakerSteve, 
Thanks a lot for taking so much time in helping out with the issue I am facing. I did the changes mentioned in change 1 and change 2 (first approach). I also checked the Manifest generated in the apk to confirm that it is not adding any Android 12 permission. But the app still has the issue when upgrading from previous version.

I was not able to try using usesPermissionFlags as the build itself fails due to the app targeting Android 11 (API Level 30).

Comment: On checking the manifest in the previous version of the app, I see that it had added BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission which is Android 12 permission which I think was added due to the use of Twilio.AudioSwitch v1.1.3 but the new apk which uses Twilio.AudioSwitch v1.1.2 does not have this permission added.

I have a feeling that the OS marks the application as an Android 12 application and then continues to behave in that way even after app updates.

Comment: @vores4u - ah, so it did add a new permission. While this isn't a practical solution for user upgrades, if you installed an upgrade that had NO BLUETOOTH permissions at all, that might remove the Android 12 bluetooth association. Then a second upgrade with only Android 11 Bluetooth permissions might succeed.

Comment: I will try this out and let you know.

Answer (score -1):

No, it can't be changed dynamically you have to change it from gradle by yourself.

Comment: Yes, that is what I expect. But the app which I have on the Play Store is targeting Android API Level 30 and even on the app submission page it shows it correctly. But the app behaves like it is targeting Android API Level 31 when installed on an Android 12 device due to the presence of Twilio Audio Switch v1.1.3 package. This is really strange for me.

Comment: In the context of this question, this could be an appropriate *comment* - but is not a useful *answer*. Question-asker isn't asking how to change it; they are asking why the app seems to be behaving "as if" it somehow automatically changed. And what they can do to prevent the symptom described in question.