# Xamarin app upgrade to lower version dependency

Tags: xamarin.forms

The app referred here is built using Xamarin Forms. I'd like to know if there is way to update/upgrade an existing app to use a lower version dependency. Example: If my release version app is 2.0 and it used a library X with version 2.5, will it be possible to have the next release version of app as 2.1 to use library X version 2.4, and force the existing installation to use X v2.4?

The problem definition is related to an issue, where a newer version of library was used and has a certain bug which is not existing on the lower version of the library. Hence we want to downgrade the library version with the next release.

Observation: The new version of app when upgrades, it is seen that it does not use the lower version (i.e. 2.4) of the library and instead uses the same 2.5 version, until the app is re-installed.

Is there a way to get this working without re-install of the app?

Comment: you can't change the library version an existing app install uses.  You can downgrade a library in the next version of an app.

Comment: @Jason Yes, that is what I am trying to do, that we update the app from 2.0 to 2.1 and in 2.1 I am downgrading the lib used but the end-user mobile which already have the app installed when it upgrades it still does not use the lower version as expected.

Comment: no, app bundles are completely overwritten on install or update

Comment: **1)** What symptom indicated it was still using previously installed version? **2)** Is this **Bluetooth** related? An [earlier SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71709675/199364) inferred that **Android OS update seems to mark apps that in SDK 31 would require new permissions**. NO solution was found. AFAIK, users will have to uninstall & reinstall the app. **3)** If it is a `Nuget`, did you verify that no projects in solution refer to the unwanted version? **4)**  To be sure the change was made, delete all `bin` and `obj` folders in project.

Comment: According to your description, you want to use something like the hotfix in the android to downgrade the dependency version. But I can not find this, it seems that the user need to download the installation package of the new app version and install it to change the dependency version in the app.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thank you, yes the issue is similar. It's unfortunate that app has to be re-installed for downgrading the dependency.